# Can't call useState hook in arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im currently trying to implement the tic tac toe example from react but using hooks and ES6 standards but I cant seem to be able to call useState. I keep getting these errors:

> Line 6:33:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "game" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

My current versions are:
 "react": "^16.12.0",
 "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
 "react-scripts": "3.4.0"

This is my current code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Restart from "../../Components/Restart/Restart";
import Square from "../../Components/Square/Square";

const game = () => {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
  const [isXNext, setIsXNext] = useState(true);
  const nextSymbol = isXNext ? "X" : "O";
  const winner = calculateWinner(squares);
  ...
  return (
    <div className="container">
  );
};
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `<div className="container">`. You don't close the div, therefore you're not returning a component, you're just returning the opening tag.

Comment: @JMadelaine it does close I just didn't want it to be so long should've added ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to capitalize the component name. Link to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)